# Accumulate messages in queues and delayed consumption with Masstransit with RabbitMq transport

Tags: .net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

I have a particular use cases were my application, on startup, needs to generate a temporary queue, let messages accumulate while initializing, and only after initialization is completed start a consumer to this temporary queue.

The best option would be to create the queues still as auto-delete, but not start a consumer on them yet, and then attach a consumer later on after some initialization work is completed.

is this even possible with MassTransit ?

I cannot find a way to be able to do this with MassTransit and .net core. This is an example of the code i am using :

` serviceCollection.AddMassTransit(busConfigurator =>
{
busConfigurator.AddConsumer();

```
busConfigurator.UsingRabbitMq((ctx, cfg) =>
{
    cfg.Host("rabbitmq://localhost");
    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(queue =>
    {
        queue.ConfigureConsumer<MyConsumer>(ctx);
    });
});
```

});`

as soon as the application starts, the consumer starts consuming messages, and i have no control over this.
I also tried working with the IBusControl interface but stopping it will also remove the queues (of course, since they are vreated as auto-delete) .

Answer (score 0):

You can use [endpoint dependencies](https://youtu.be/ZZdpz9StKCA) to block the receive endpoint from starting until you're ready for messages to be consumed.